# ConcurrentDictionary and threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrentdictionary

I have a WCF service in IIS App pool. Method of WCF service receives some data in JSON, like {"object": "someobject", "payload": [int key]}.
For each request I running new thread to work with key.
Key is adding to ConcurrentDictionary and locks value of ConcurrentDictionary.
Purpose of this is: only one examplar of key can run one time, example:
**Thread 1**-Running with **key 1**
**Thread 2**-Running with **key 2**
**Thread 3**-Waiting **lock in Thread 1**
But when I remove key from ConcurrentDictionary, another thread already get the value by key and works with it. How to avoid this?
Example of thread handler near

```c
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> taskDictionary=new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
static void ThreadHandler(int key)
        {   
            try
            {
                var  lockElem=taskDictionary.GetOrAdd(key, new object());
//Thread 3 get value by key 1 here and waits here
                lock(lockElem)
                {
                    taskDictionary.TryRemove(key, out _);
// but Thread 1 removes value by key 1 here
//and Thread 4 can add value in Dictionary with same key (key 1)
                }
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
```

Problem is in this case: Thread 1 uses GetOrAdd, then lock value, then TryRemove. In this time Thread 3. uses GetOrAdd, taking value, but waiting lock from Thread 1. When lock from Thread 1 releases, Thread 3 lock removed value. In this time Thread 4 uses GetOrAdd, and creating new dictionary element (which not match with value taken by Thread 3). And we have 2 threads (Thread 3 and Thread 4) which working with same key.

Comment: This is more about your solution (algorithm) than about thread-safety. You could solve the first problem with ContainsKey inside the lock. But when a key can be re-added you will have to specify the logic better here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman how to check inside the lock that value with key does not exists? When key removes, another Thread (Thread 4 for example) add new value in dictionary

Comment: Well, you've got the Dictionary and you have the key... And you can use `!`.

Comment: sorry, im not understand

Comment: I've made it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The TryRemove function already gives you back a default object if it does not exist in the dictionary yet, so you could simply do:

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<int, object> taskDictionary=new ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>();
static void ThreadHandler(int key)
{   
    try
    {
        object obj;

        // Remove object with key = 'key', or create a new object if it does not yet exist
        taskDictionary.TryRemove(key, out obj);

        // Do whatever you need to do with 'obj'

        // Add the object (back) to the dictionary if necessary
        taskDictionary.GetOrAdd(key, obj);
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: how it help me in lock element by key?

Comment: You remove the key from the Dictionary, so there is no longer any need to lock the element, since no other thread will be able to fetch it from the DIctionary.

Comment: but first thread, what want access to object, cant get object by TryRemove, right?

Comment: Yes, TryRemove will return the object that has been removed from the Dictionary. Because the method is atomic, only one thread will be able to access the element before it is removed. Please see here for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryremove?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: How help the first thread to add a element to dictionary? I need than another threads waiting until lock is released, coz it's like queue of requests to dictionary, the next thread with same key need to wait, while previous worker do work.

Comment: In that case I do not fully understand the problem with your initial code, because there the second thread will wait under the first thread is finished with the element. Maybe you can update your question to make it more clear what you are exactly trying to achieve.

Comment: Problem is in this case: Thread 1 uses GetOrAdd, then lock value, then TryRemove. In this time Thread 3. uses GetOrAdd, taking value, but waiting lock from Thread 1. When lock from Thread 1 releases, Thread 3 lock removed value. In this time Thread 4 uses GetOrAdd, and creating new dictionary element (which not match with value taken by Thread 3). And we have 2 threads (Thread 3 and Thread 4) which working with same key.

Comment: I think instead of describing the problem, you could better describe the requirements of what you are trying to achieve. When are items added to the dictionary? Can there be multiple items with the same key? Can items be processed multiple times? Or should they be deleted after being processed?

Comment: Items adding to dictionary before lock. Cannot be multiple items with same key. Items can be processed multiple times, but not same key in same time. They should be deleted after execution of thread.

Comment: maybe me need just use in lock Interlocked.CompareExchange on locked value and read value in dictionary?